# Need to add dependencies in my project

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I have a project1 in eclipse and that needs to be depend on other project2 in the same workspace. So my structure for that project1 is-

```
src/
projects.xml
```

So is there any way that if I add the dependencies of project2 in projects.xml file then my code will work fine. I don't want to do it this way- By right clicking on the project1 and then go to build path and from there add the project2 as a dependency. Any way that we can do it in projects.xml file and how we can do it. Any suggestions will be appreciated?
So this is my content of projects.xml file that I have added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project canSkipOnJdk13="true" hasV4Content="false" hasV4Css="false" hasV4Flash="false" hasV4Js="false" isFlash="false" isSysJar="false" isTest="false" mustBuild="false" path="v4tracking" type="JAR" v4extractresource="false">
    <src>
        <dir isTest="false" path="src"/>
        <dir isTest="false" path="meta-src"/>
        <dir isTest="true" path="tests"/>
    </src>
    <dependencies>
        <library name="MarketPlaceServiceCommonTypeLibrary"/>
        <library name="SOAClient"/>
        <library name="SOACommonTypeLibrary"/>
        <library name="SOATools"/>
        <library name="eBoxServiceCommon"/>
        <library name="jaxb2"/>
        <service_library name="PersonalizationV1"/>
        <project name="SOAGlobalConfig"/>
        <!-- for local binding -->
        <project name="CoreDomain"/>
        <project name="GlobalEnvironment"/>
        <project name="DALTracking"/>
        <project name="PersonalizationV1Impl"/>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But by this way it is not working. Any idea how can I do the same?

Comment: I am using eclipse and I have chosen Java Project here and I created projects.xml file manually. And I am not sure how can I achieve this building everything from my projects.xml file

Comment: Why do you create this file? Why do you think it is used by anything? Where did you get that XML grammar?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [maven](http://maven.apache.org). However this is very likely overkill for your problem.

Comment: I don't want to use Maven. It has to be Java project. and build it from projects.xml file.

Comment: Maven is a java tool that can be used for dependency managment. It also allows to configure your Java project workspace. It no coding just configuration.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But that way it has to be maven project and then in the pom.xml I can add that right? But any way we can do this using Java project?

Comment: Yes. However they are java projects. The pom is just for configuration of your java project.